Pytorch Geometric Dataloader is doing strange things
I'm trying to train my network model and I need a dataloader for that. The dataloader is returning different results in the first iteration over the dataset compared to the second iteration. How is this possible?
Code:
from Pointcloud.Modules.FileDataset import FileDataset
from Pointcloud.Modules import Config as config

dm = FileDataset(config.DATA_DIR, split_name=config.SPLIT_NAME, split=config.SPLIT)
train_dl = dm.train_dataloader(config.BATCH_SIZE, config.NUM_WORKERS)

for i in range(2):
    sum = 0
    for j, minibatch in enumerate(train_dl):
        if j < 8: # Only showing the first 8 iterations to show the problem.
            print(j, minibatch.batch.unique(return_counts=True))
        sum += 1
    print(f"Iteration {i}\nNumber of iterations: {sum}\nNumber of batches: {len(train_dl.dataset) / config.BATCH_SIZE}")

Output:
train bs: 25008
val bs: 8335
test bs: 8339
0 (tensor([0], device='cuda:0'), tensor([756], device='cuda:0'))
1 (tensor([0], device='cuda:0'), tensor([756], device='cuda:0'))
2 (tensor([0], device='cuda:0'), tensor([774], device='cuda:0'))
3 (tensor([0], device='cuda:0'), tensor([787], device='cuda:0'))
4 (tensor([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
       device='cuda:0'), tensor([39, 60, 44, 54, 52, 50, 51, 48, 36, 54, 61, 51, 51, 56, 55, 48],
       device='cuda:0'))
5 (tensor([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
       device='cuda:0'), tensor([47, 54, 56, 50, 51, 26, 75, 48, 43, 52, 55, 53, 35, 38, 51, 43],
       device='cuda:0'))
6 (tensor([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
       device='cuda:0'), tensor([47, 62, 53, 50, 54, 53, 52, 48, 57, 50, 53, 43, 53, 47, 59, 56],
       device='cuda:0'))
7 (tensor([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
       device='cuda:0'), tensor([52, 39, 43, 49, 52, 40, 49, 52, 52, 72, 57, 36, 28, 53, 50, 52],
       device='cuda:0'))
Iteration 0
Number of iterations: 1563
Number of batches: 1563.0
0 (tensor([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
       device='cuda:0'), tensor([43, 46, 50, 52, 53, 49, 63, 50, 36, 49, 53, 51, 40, 51, 56, 46],
       device='cuda:0'))
1 (tensor([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
       device='cuda:0'), tensor([50, 64, 44, 55, 54, 53, 53, 50, 49, 44, 52, 51, 47, 38, 54, 45],
       device='cuda:0'))
2 (tensor([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
       device='cuda:0'), tensor([44, 52, 49, 53, 49, 48, 52, 51, 44, 51, 42, 49, 53, 61, 46, 50],
       device='cuda:0'))
3 (tensor([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
       device='cuda:0'), tensor([59, 50, 40, 47, 33, 54, 59, 63, 53, 46, 44, 40, 49, 52, 53, 36],
       device='cuda:0'))
4 (tensor([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
       device='cuda:0'), tensor([54, 53, 49, 55, 54, 46, 28, 43, 45, 46, 51, 60, 49, 48, 54, 48],
       device='cuda:0'))
5 (tensor([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
       device='cuda:0'), tensor([54, 44, 59, 50, 45, 50, 35, 40, 54, 47, 39, 52, 52, 39, 50, 55],
       device='cuda:0'))
6 (tensor([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
       device='cuda:0'), tensor([49, 51, 42, 40, 51, 46, 48, 52, 45, 52, 38, 43, 50, 44, 49, 41],
       device='cuda:0'))
7 (tensor([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
       device='cuda:0'), tensor([49, 54, 61, 52, 48, 50, 36, 47, 49, 56, 41, 43, 52, 52, 54, 39],
       device='cuda:0'))
Iteration 1
Number of iterations: 1563
Number of batches: 1563.0

The dataset is a list of Pytorch Geometric Data objects, with the first 5 elements being:
[Data(x=[59, 8], edge_index=[2, 357], y=[1, 3]),
 Data(x=[50, 8], edge_index=[2, 292], y=[1, 3]),
 Data(x=[52, 8], edge_index=[2, 324], y=[1, 3]),
 Data(x=[56, 8], edge_index=[2, 362], y=[1, 3]),
 Data(x=[44, 8], edge_index=[2, 256], y=[1, 3])]

The creation of the dataloader is done by the following function:
def train_dataloader(self, batch_size, num_workers):
    return tg_loader_DataLoader(
        dataset=self.train_ds,
        batch_size=batch_size,
        shuffle=True,
        num_workers=num_workers,
        persistent_workers=True,
        drop_last=True
    )

Can someone help me with why the dataloader is not loading correctly? It is merging batches now, setting all values within the batch to zero. This results in nonsense data, which crashes the forwards pass through the model and also misses data to train on, since some data is overwritten :(
As described in the problem above

Your train_dataloader code sets shuffle=True. This means the dataloader shuffles the dataset and returns items in a different order every time.

Thanks for your comment! I've tried setting shuffle=False, but that doesn't solve the problem sadly. However, I have discovered that settings config.NUM_WORKERS to 2 results in only 2 wrong results. This suggests that the first result from the dataloader is incorrect and afterwards everything is fine. But why is this and how do I fix the problem?

The tensors from my dataset were on the GPU. As described in the second warning on this page, it is recommended to store your dataset on the cpu and use a Dataloader to put it on the GPU.
